# PHP7 under Alpine in Docker command not found

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

When I run an interactive shell for the container there definitely is a PHP binary:

```
sudo docker run -t -i neekoy/php7 /bin/sh

/ # which php-fpm7

/usr/sbin/php-fpm7
```

But when I run that same container I get the following:

```
sudo docker run neekoy/php7

/bin/sh: [php-fpm7]: not found
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update

RUN apk add php7-fpm php7-mcrypt php7-soap php7-openssl php7-gmp php7-pdo_odbc php7-json php7-dom php7-pdo php7-zip php7-mysqli php7-sqlite3 php7-apcu php7-pdo_pgsql php7-bcmath php7-gd php7-odbc php7-pdo_mysql php7-pdo_sqlite php7-gettext php7-xmlreader php7-xmlrpc php7-bz2 php7-iconv php7-pdo_dblib php7-curl php7-ctype

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ['php-fpm7']
```

I've stripped out the config changes because they're irrelevant.

System info:

> ## Container:
>
> cat /etc/*release*
>
> 3.7.0
>
> NAME="Alpine Linux"
>
> ## My PC:
>
> docker -v
>
> Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

Comment: Have you tried using the whole path from `which` in the CMD? Like `CMD ['/usr/sbin/php-fpm7']`?

Comment: Yeah - I tried with the full path too, same result.

Comment: Ah, you have to use double quotes like `CMD ["php-fpm7"]` - single quotes aparently do not work.

Comment: Also, you do not want to run fpm as a daemon, so you have to actually use this: `CMD ["php-fpm7", "-F"]` (`-F` = no daemonize).

Comment: Ha, you're correct - it even changed the highlighting when I switched to double quotes. Works this way. Can you submit it as an answer so I can mark it in case someone stumbles upon this?

Comment: Ah yes, I also want to run it in the foreground so it wouldn't close the container. Cheers for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that single quotes `'` do not work - according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) the argument is parsed as JSON-array. So the correct "CMD"-line would look like this:

```
CMD ["php-fpm7", "-F"]
```